# VS Code isn't reading <ranges> library

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, c++20

Even though I've included the < ranges > header in my code the compiler doesn't register it and causes errors when I try to run the code.

```cpp
    #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <numeric>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <ranges>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    int main() {
        for (int i : views::iota(1, 11)) //this is the function supposedly included in the <ranges> library
            cout << i << endl;
        return 0;
    };
```

When I run`std::cout << __cplusplus` I get the output `202002` which means that in theory VS Code and the compiler are successfully reading that it's C++20. My compiler version is Apple clang version 13.1.6. I'm not sure how to change the language standard, but since I'm getting the C++20 output then it should have the right standard?

I've tried online compilers and the code runs just fine. Any idea on something else I can try?

Comment: Do you have a compiler that's capable of C++20, and have you configured VS Code for C++20?

Comment: How are you compiling the code? Which compiler and version are you using?

Comment: And have you set the language standard for your local compiler to C++20?

Comment: Apple clang doesn't support ranges: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support